# How can i Populate a grid with rest service using PHP Laravel dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have created page with Datatable and its code is given below

```
$('#test').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "http://www.****.com/***/patientInfo"
    } );
```

This ajax URL will give list of Patients list in JSON format

```
<table id="test" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>First name</th>
     <th>Last name</th>
     <th>Position</th>
     <th>Office</th>
     <th>Start date</th>
     <th>Salary</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
   <tr>
     <th>First name</th>
     <th>Last name</th>
     <th>Position</th>
     <th>Office</th>
     <th>Start date</th>
     <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Now i couldn't achieve it. I got an error, i prompting that Datatable Warning: Table id=test, Invalid JSON response.

I want to show all the JSON data in the Datatable from Ajax URL.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This [page](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) shows DataTables own server side script using `ssp.class.php`, basically the server-side script needs to return data in the format described [here](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side) under the title Returned data, DataTables sends it's data (the variables your laravel page will need to consume) in the form detailed under the title Sent parameters. A good start would be to simple var_dump the Sent parameters and work from there to build up your server side script

Comment: I have gone through the page which you referred already. But my doubt is that I am deliberately sends the Ajax data as the output from the jquery's Ajax URL. So it should render the table with that data right?

Comment: DataTables is smart enough to send what you want, to check: open the developer tools and check what the payload is to `"http://www.****.com/***/patientInfo"`. Decoded from [this](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/td4zypgm/) is this: http://www.****.com/***/patientInfo?draw=1&columns[0][data]=0&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][searchable]=true&columns[0][orderable]=true...`lots of other stuff`. How you'd deal with that in laravel is up to you. It does need to return json in the form detailed on the DataTables website.

Comment: I am beginner in this Datatable. So i don't have much idea on consuming like through Querystring kind of stuff. Could you do it on Fiddler or Can you send your email ID please?

Comment: I added a JSFiddle in my last reply with a working DataTable. Copy that to your page and alter the `"ajax"` URI to your one and then get to work on writing a script to populate the response. My links in my original comment should give you everything you need to work out what should go into your response. [This](https://drmsite.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/datatables-custom-server-side-script.html) might help as well as an example of a custom script to return the correct data - though it does use Medoo to make the query.